# I can not connect to the device for Bluetooth LE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using Bluetooth LE. Other devices it finds, but it cannot connect to it and get the data that it sends the device.

```
nameDeviceList.clear();
deviceList.clear();
listView = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_devices);
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameDeviceList);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
    (BluetoothManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
scanLeDevice(true);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Application.writeFileSDBLT(deviceList.get(position).getName());
        g = deviceList.get(position).connectGatt(gView.getContext(), false, mGattCallback);

        // Application.writeFileSDBLT(g.getServices().get(0).getCharacteristics().get(0).getUuid().toString());

    }
});
```

The method of scanning devices:

```
public void scanLeDevice(boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}




private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        /**
         * Callback indicating when GATT client has connected/disconnected to/from a remote
         * GATT server.
         *
         * @param gatt     GATT client
         * @param status   Status of the connect or disconnect operation.
         *                 {@link BluetoothGatt#GATT_SUCCESS} if the operation succeeds.
         * @param newState Returns the new connection state. Can be one of
         *                 {@link BluetoothProfile#STATE_DISCONNECTED} or
         *                 {@link BluetoothProfile#STATE_CONNECTED}
         */
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            //super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {

                Application.writeFileSDBLT(" BLT _Connected ");
                g.discoverServices();
               // onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);


            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Application.writeFileSDBLT("DISCONNECTED BLT _Connected ");
            }

        }

        /**
         * Callback reporting the result of a characteristic read operation.
         *
         * @param gatt           GATT client invoked {@link BluetoothGatt#readCharacteristic}
         * @param characteristic Characteristic that was read from the associated
         *                       remote device.
         * @param status         {@link BluetoothGatt#GATT_SUCCESS} if the read operation
         */
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
           // super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
           String UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT = SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT;
            if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)
                Application.writeFileSDBLT("GAAT Connection Success");
            else
                Application.writeFileSDBLT("GAAT Connection Failed");


        }

        /**
         * Callback invoked when the list of remote services, characteristics and descriptors
         * for the remote device have been updated, ie new services have been discovered.
         *
         * @param gatt   GATT client invoked {@link BluetoothGatt#discoverServices}
         * @param status {@link BluetoothGatt#GATT_SUCCESS} if the remote device
         */
        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            //super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)
            Application.writeFileSDBLT("GATT Connection SERVICESS :onServicesDiscovered + size services: "+gatt.getServices().size());
          else
                Application.writeFileSDBLT("GATT no Connection Services");
           // Application.writeFileSDBLT("asdssssssssssssf-"+gatt.getServices().get(0).getCharacteristics().size());


        }
    };
```

Comment: I suppose you should debug and see what gets executed, and what values are given with status variables.